# Can't get Mouse back in gEdit after Shift Key Is Pressed

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, 14.04, mouse, gedit

By default when you type in **gEdit**, mouse disappears and you can get it back by moving your mouse. So, you can do whatever you want using your mouse.

But when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> and move the mouse to get the it back on screen, it won't work. The mouse will be shown when it's moved and suddenly disappears. So, I can't do any actions using it. This is a very weird bug. To get back the mouse, I have to right click on the editor.

Is this a known bug? How can I fix it? Has only **gEdit** (version **3.10.4**) have this bug? Should I downgrade it to lower version?

I've tested this on **leafpad Text Editor** and this problem doesn't exist there.

### 2nd Bug

When you're typing for a while (like 30 minutes or more), sometimes **gEdit** won't allow typing anymore, but you can save the file and do other stuff. There won't be any cursor to make it normal again, you have to close the **gEdit** window and start new one.

As far as I tested, this "new gEdit" is way too buggy.

Is there any other lightweight (or not) text editors like **gEdit** with code markup and other stuff ?

### UPDATE

When **gEdit** is ran in root (`gksudo gedit`), this bug doesn't seem to exist. So, why does this bug occur in normal user and not in root ?

Comment: Are you just pressing those keys once, or holding them down to cause the mouse to do this?

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem too after I use the Find command (Ctrl+F). If you run `top` in a terminal do you also find that `ibus-daemon` eats around 50% CPU. This problem started when I upgraded to Lubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @Nattgew When any of the keys are pressed once, this problem occurs.

Comment: If I start my window manager from a console (with startx) I don't have this problem in Gedit, so there must be some service/daemon that causes this. Maybe we can disable it.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Yes, On my system too, `ibus-daemon` takes too much CPU memory. Does this bug exist only on `Lubuntu` and not in `Ubuntu` ? So, there is no workaround to fix this problem ?

Comment: Do you happen to use an Nvidia graphics card? Do you use the default nouveau driver? I think it can be graphics card/driver related.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom I'm currentlyy using Nvidia driver. At first, when I installed Lubuntu with nouveau driver, the system crashes when Firefox / chrome is opened. gEdit still shows the same bug even if I change the driver to nouveau. So, I don't think it's a driver issue. With Nvidia driver enabled, system doesn't crash when Chrome/Firefox is opened.

Comment: @Subin I cannot reproduce this bug in Ubuntu 12.04. Will test in Lubuntu 14.04 ASAP. I'm glad you found a solution that works for you.

Comment: I can confirm that this bug exists in Lubuntu 14.04. The included Leafpad app doesn't have this issue. You can't get the mouse back in gedit until you click outside the gedit window (say on the desktop) Opening gedit from a terminal and typing a capital letter using the shift key I get this error: (gedit:2890): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Comment: @ElderGeek I get that error when I type any characters. Can you reproduce the mouse bug when **gEdit** is ran by root ?

Comment: @Subin yes. Same error if I type a capital using the shift (in Ubuntu 14.04) I'll check Lubuntu again after my updates are complete.

Comment: Correction. The above should say Warning, not Error

Comment: @Subin yes. In fact now I get the exact same results as you are getting. I'm not sure why I didn't get the warning without the shift key before (I know I hadn't rebooted but that shouldn't matter)

Comment: Since the problem seems to be caused by IBus, a work-around is to disable it by setting *Keyboard input method system* to *none* in `gnome-language-selector`.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom I did what you said, but the bug still exists.

Comment: @Subin So you experience mouse flicker despite IBus not running? What does `top` show?

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Yes, you were right. Changing from `IBus` to none solves the problem. It didn't work form e before, because I didn't reboot the system. Is there any bad effects disabling `IBus` ?

Comment: @Subin Restarting X Windows (logging out) should be enough I think. If you don't need to switch between different input methods you don't need IBus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug has not been fixed and I decided to switch to another text editor. I found **[Geany](http://www.geany.org)** and it's great. It does not have the bug like that on **gEdit**.

So, I guess the solution is to switch to a new text editor until (or not) this bug is fixed.

### Features of Geany

- Lightweight
- Have Basic Features of an IDE
- Faster than gEdit
- few dependencies
- Supports many filetypes
- Have Plugins & Code Markup (Syntax Highlighting)
- Kind of like gEdit (Disable view of Sidebar & Messages Window)

### UPDATE - Bug Fixed

As [reported by August Karlstrom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456739/cant-get-mouse-back-in-gedit-after-shift-key-is-pressed#comment616468_456739), The **gEdit** mouse bug was fixed when I disabled **IBus** as the default Keyboard Input System. Here's how you can disable it :

Open a terminal and do the command :

> gnome-language-selector

A window named **Language Support** will open up. In the window, change the **Keyboard input method system** option to `none` instead of `IBus` and close the window.
[image: GNOME Language Selector Window]

The changes would only take effect after you restart (reboot) your computer.

Comment: yes i too have tried it[Geany] and its flawless without any bug

Answer (score 1):

Just install ibus-gtk:

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-gtk
```

And open again your session.

source:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/1377370

Comment: This is the flawless solution if you wanna use gedit and ibus together. If it was up to me, this would be the accepted answer.